# Deploying my adapter to mobile first server takes very long

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, maximo-anywhere

It tends to take 12-15 minutes to deploy my adapter to the WL server.  Sometimes it times out at 20 minutes.  Just now, after timing out at 20 multiple times in a row, it finally deployed after 19 minutes.  Other people on my team don't seem to have this problem and their adapters (the same one I'm using) deploys in 2 or 3 minutes.

I assume there is some setting or property I have wrong.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting. It sounds more like network related. I would check what is different between your machine and theirs network-wise.

For example, I've observed this could happen if switching between VPN environment to non-VPN environment. After switching to one of those, try restarting then see if it continues.

Also check for any other environment differences between you and them.

Comment: I'm running on localhost, so I don't think its network-related.  I was running fine on my old laptop.  I got a new, "faster" laptop and now have this problem.  So yes, I'm sure its environmental, but the question remains, what?  How can it even be debugged, traced?

Comment: There was a similar issue in the past, which is why I am saying it may be related - are you switching between a VPNed environment to non-VPN? Does it happen after a restart? Does it happen in a new Eclipse workspace? What is your the version and build number? Does it happen w/out maximo?

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I am switching between VPN and non-VPN, but the problem occurred in both conditions.  And it happens even after restart.  So I took your other suggestion, and tried creating a new workspace.  And that seems to resolve the problem (hopefully long term).  Deploying the adapter is now taking 3 minutes.

Comment: Does it take 3 minutes to your team mates as well?

Comment: I think it takes them around 3 minutes yes.  What is concerning to me is that this morning, even with the new workspace, it took 14 minutes to start the adapter.  So I'm still looking for a way to track where the time is being spent.

Comment: If you are on 7.0, we had a fix our concern such long deployments in cases where the IP address changes but this is also why I asked if its always so slow (3 minutes is kinda slow). Anyway the fix has been out for some time now so verify you're using the latest iFix.